# Proof by contradiction in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, foundations

Can we validate proof by contradiction inside first order (or propositional) logic as formal theory? Am I right that we can use meta theorem of deduction for it ($ \phi \vdash (\psi \land \neg \psi) \Rightarrow  \vdash \phi \rightarrow (\psi \land \neg \psi) \Rightarrow$ ..contraposition derivation.. $  (\psi \lor \neg \psi) \rightarrow \neg \phi. MP \neg \phi $ ).

Thanks.

Comment: In propositional logic, $P$ is equivalent to $\neg P\Rightarrow f$, where $f$  denotes false.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'validate it inside FOL as formal theory'? You mean: can we derive it from other principles? If so, I would say it depends on what other principles you do or do not have. In fact, the Deduction Theorem depends on that as well: if you don't have enough rules or principles, the Deduction Theorem may not hold for that particular set of rules and principles.